# issue with ie on the events -jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jsfiddle which is not responding to events in ie. not sure what is happening
http://jsfiddle.net/H6KBW/91/

Comment: another issue ...the jsfiddle is not working in ie7 for the footer width , it is not streching to 100% width..want to understand what is happening behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a little trick to get past this in IE. Try adding these two lines to your #photoeditor-nav css class:

```
opacity:0.01;
background:white;
```

The background color is undetectable to the human eye and it allows the event to bubble off the div in IE.

Comment: I need more explanation of how it is working...some I may have to wait for others to answer

Comment: Sorry, just got back to this one. In IE the div DOM element won't accept a click event on any portions of it that are transparent. So if your div was fully transparent but you had a solid border, you'd be able to get the click event to fire by clicking on the border but not inside the div, because the transparency inside the div is treated as though there's nothing there, so the event can't bubble to the div's event.

Comment: Setting the opacity to a super small value paired with giving the div a background color sets the background of the div thus allowing the browser to recognize a click event "on" the div. The background color could be anything, the point is to give the mouse something to click on, the small opacity setting makes it virtually invisible so it doesn't compromise the appearance of anything inside/behind the div.

Comment: Did this explanation help you?